# store getter returns observer object instead of null

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I would like to create a simple "Conway's Game of Life" application and store the settings that have already been made to the localStorage.

I created three views

- Map Settings
  | Define map size etc.
- Map Setup
  | Create a preset for your map
- Map Launch
  | Launch your preset

Whenever the settings change the preset has to be deleted because the preset might have a different old size. The settings use default values if the localStorage is empty.

Within my store I save the map setup to the `grid` property. So the value is either `null` or a two dimensional array from the localStorage.

When routing to the *MapSetup.vue* file I use the mounted event to setup the preset

```
  mounted: function() {
    if (this.grid) { // the preset from the store / localStorage
      this.currentGrid = this.grid; // use the preset
    } else {
      this.currentGrid = this.generateNewMap(); // generate a new preset
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately `this.grid` (store getter) is not null and returns an `__ob__ observer` item. Because of this the `if` statement is **truthy** and will not generate a new preset.

I created a working example of my application here

https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-vuex-and-vuerouter-h6yqu

You can define the settings in *MapSettings.vue* and the `grid` state from mapSetup should be set to `null`. After redirecting to *MapSetup.vue* no grid should appear because `this.grid` returns `__ob__ observer` instead of null.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try to cast it: `if (!! this.grid) ...` ?

Comment: Hey, sorry no, would you mind explaining why I should do so =?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[MutationTypes.RESET_MAP_SETUP]: state => {
    state.grid = [];
}
```

when you reset the grid, you set it as an empty array, not as null
that is why it's not null in your mounted hook

Comment: @ Benoît Schiex yes that's one mistake he made but did you try his sandbox? I still get an empty card although the grid contains the correct data

Comment: stupid mistake by me but the grid still won't update as Question3r already mentioned ...